# Bandwidth stats on wifi for each network?

Tags: wifi, osx, router, bandwidth

Is it posible to have the bandwidth usage of the wifi connection for each network I use?
Currently I have vnstat instaled on my MacBook Pro retina runing Yosemite. It works well but I have the usage from ALL the networks I use.
My problem is that my home connection is bandwidth capped while the other two I use at work are not. I want to know how the home connection is growing before i got the cap.